# back button in an iframe (BUG?)

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, safari

I am trying to implement a back button in an iframe for safari using javascript. Basically, I created a website using 5 iframes. In one of those iframes, there is a back button that uses simple javascript.

```
<a href="javascript:history.back()">&laquo; Go back</a>
```

Everything seems to work fine with IE but when I test my website in Safari this Back button acts like it is using `window.history.go(-1)`.

I also read this link: http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-hashchange/examples/bug-webkit-hash-iframe/ and I am not sure what to do.

Any ideas to fix this issue? Also tried javascript: `self.history.go(-1)` but had no luck.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript back button in an iframe (safari)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938314/javascript-back-button-in-an-iframe-safari)

Comment: Added the link that explains the prob

Comment: @bobo, yes, but edit your original Q, dont post a new one.

Comment: I have jquery tabs each tab contains an iframe url